# Loading APK into TestDroid

Tags: android, user-interface, automation, testdroid

I am having a problem loading an .apk into Testdroid, as in this tutorial:

http://testdroid.com/testdroid-recorder-recording-without-source-code

When I get to step 8, and hit "Browse", I get the following error:

"Problem occurred by signing apk. Please contact with support(support@bitbar.com)."

I have tried setting the debuggable flag true, and checking the "I have DEBUGGABLE flag set...etc." Has anyone else had this problem and resolved it? More generally, does anyone know of any other UI automation packages that don't require having the source?

Answer (score 1):

Before a moment new version of recorder was out and this should be fixed. Try to update.